# Reduce column width of table while also aligning values at decimal point

Tags: tables, tabularx, siunitx, dcolumn

I have a table that is currently too large for my page which is why I want to reduce the column width. At the same time I also want to align the values at the decimal point. I have been trying with the `siunitx` package but somehow I can't get it right. I don't necessarily have to use this package but I want the table to stay the way it is (except for the column widths). I would like to adjust each column width individually to overall make the table the same width as the text I have in my document.

This is my table:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}  
\usepackage[format=hang,font={small,it},labelfont={bf,it},labelsep=space]{caption} 
\captionsetup[table]{labelsep=space,justification=raggedright,singlelinecheck=off}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htb]
    \caption{Sample caption \label{tab:example}}
      \begin{tabular}{rlSllSl}
      \toprule
      & TEXTEXTEXT & AR & t-stat & Firms & AR & t-stat \\ 
      \midrule
      & X TEXTEXTEXT & & & & \\
      \midrule
      1 & TEXTEXTEXT & 0.0056 & (0.46) & TEXTEXTEXT & 0.0046 & (0.37) \\ 
      2 & TEXTEXTEXT & -0.0067 & (-0.45) & TEXTEXTEXT & 0.0062 & (0.63) \\ 
      3 & TEXTEXTEXT & 0.0006 & (0.07) & TEXTEXTEXT & -0.0036 & (-0.31) \\ 
      4 & TEXTEXTEXT & -0.0005 & (-0.05) & TEXTEXTEXT & 0.0054 & (0.35) \\ 
      5 & TEXTEXTEXT & 0.0029 & (0.34) & TEXTEXTEXT & 0.0046 & (0.39) \\ 
      6 & TEXTEXTEXT & 0.0034 & (0.30) & TEXTEXTEXT & 0.0103 & (1.12) \\ 
      7 & TEXTEXTEXT & 0.0063 & (0.38) & & & \\ 
      8 & TEXTEXTEXT & -0.0006 & (-0.07) & & & \\ 
      9 & TEXTEXTEXT & -0.0037 & (-0.29) & & & \\ 
      10 & TEXTEXTEXT & -0.0017 & (-0.19) & & & \\ 
      11 & TEXTEXTEXT & -0.0005 & (-0.06) & & & \\ 
      12 & TEXTEXTEXT & 0.0048 & (0.57) & & & \\ 
      13 & TEXTEXTEXT & 0.0054 & (0.52) & & & \\ 
      14 & TEXTEXTEXT & 0.0026 & (0.25) & & & \\ 
      \midrule
      & Y TEXTEXTEXT & & & & \\
      \midrule
      1 & TEXTEXTEXT & 0.0001 & (0.01) & ATEXTEXTEXT & 0.0137 & (1.59)* \\ 
      2 & TEXTEXTEXT & -0.0014 & (-0.12) & TEXTEXTEXT & 0.0105 & (1.15) \\ 
      3 & TEXTEXTEXT & 0.0107 & (1.48)* & TEXTEXTEXT & 0.0061 & (0.55) \\ 
      4 & TEXTEXTEXT & 0.0040 & (0.32) & TEXTEXTEXT & 0.0109 & (0.88) \\ 
      5 & TEXTEXTEXT & 0.0091 & (1.16) & TEXTEXTEXT & 0.0044 & (0.47) \\ 
      6 & TEXTEXTEXT & 0.0034 & (0.41) & TEXTEXTEXT & -0.0021 & (-0.13) \\ 
      7 & TEXTEXTEXT & -0.0014 & (-0.13) & TEXTEXTEXT & -0.0045 & (-0.35) \\ 
      8 & TEXTEXTEXT & 0.0019 & (0.13) & TEXTEXTEXT & 0.0143 & (1.18) \\ 
      9 & TEXTEXTEXT & 0.0001 & (0.01) & TEXTEXTEXT & -0.0160 & (-1.53)* \\ 
      10 & TEXTEXTEXT & 0.0086 & (1.15) & TEXTEXTEXT & -0.0046 & (-0.15) \\ 
      11 & TEXTEXTEXT & -0.0103 & (-0.98) & TEXTEXTEXT & 0.0004 & (0.04) \\ 
      12 & TEXTEXTEXT & -0.0008 & (-0.08) & TEXTEXTEXT & -0.0015 & (-0.10) \\ 
      13 & TEXTEXTEXT & -0.0078 & (-0.68) & TEXTEXTEXT & -0.0100 & (-0.44) \\ 
      14 & TEXTEXTEXT & -0.0023 & (-0.14) & TEXTEXTEXT & 0.0054 & (0.65) \\ 
      15 & TEXTEXTEXT & -0.0065 & (-0.51) & TEXTEXTEXT & 0.0018 & (0.14) \\ 
      16 & TEXTEXTEXT & 0.0020 & (0.29) & TEXTEXTEXT & -0.0195 & (-0.91) \\ 
      17 & TEXTEXTEXT & 0.0083 & (0.82) & & \\ 
      18 & TEXTEXTEXT & 0.0009 & (0.11) & & & \\ 
      19 & TEXTEXTEXT & -0.0101 & (-0.90) & & & \\ 
      20 & TEXTEXTEXT & 0.0043 & (0.51) & & & \\ 
      21 & TEXTEXTEXT & 0.0072 & (0.75) & & & \\ 
      22 & TEXTEXTEXT & -0.0211 & (-0.94) & & & \\ 
       \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}

    {\raggedright \footnotesize{One-tailed t-statistics in parantheses

         Signs indicate * p $<$ 0.1, ** p $<$ 0.05, *** p $<$ 0.01} \par}
    \end{table}

\end{document}
```

Appreciate any help with this!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436)  Could you please turn your code fragment into a compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) by adding the documentclass as well as the relevant packages? Currently, your table is not compilable as its column specifiers are completely missing.

Comment: @leandriis Of course, sorry about that! I edited the example accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the update. However, in your previous code, the second and fifth column was a bit shorter than it is now. What is closer to the table in your real document?

Comment: @leandriis you can disregard the first example, this is closer to the real document as the columns make the table wider than the text.

Comment: Some more suggestions/questions: a) Would it be okay to introduce linebreaks in the second and fifth column? b) Are you willing to change the document's margins (for example with the `geometry` package? c) Could you rotate the table to a landscape page?

Comment: Unfortunately none of these are a real option, as the table would get too long. I also need the margins to stay the same and I cannot use landscape.

Comment: In its current form, the table is already too long for a single page as the notes overlap with the page numbers. So I'd nevertheless recomment the use of `longtable`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have something fill to one page using the MWE, perhaps using the `\usepackage{fullpage}` would be helpful in achieving that goal.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}  
\usepackage[format=hang,font={small,it},labelfont={bf,it},labelsep=space]{caption} 
\captionsetup[table]{labelsep=space,justification=raggedright,singlelinecheck=off}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{dcolumn}

\newcolumntype{L}{D{.}{.}{2,5}}

\usepackage{fullpage}

\begin{document}

    \begin{table}[!htb]
        \caption{Sample caption \label{tab:example}}
        \begin{tabular}{rlSllSl}
            \toprule
            & TEXTEXTEXT & AR & t-stat & Firms & AR & t-stat \\ 
            \midrule
            & X TEXTEXTEXT & & & & \\
            \midrule
            1 & TEXTEXTEXT & 0.0056 & (0.46) & TEXTEXTEXT & 0.0046 & (0.37) \\ 
            2 & TEXTEXTEXT & -0.0067 & (-0.45) & TEXTEXTEXT & 0.0062 & (0.63) \\ 
            3 & TEXTEXTEXT & 0.0006 & (0.07) & TEXTEXTEXT & -0.0036 & (-0.31) \\ 
            4 & TEXTEXTEXT & -0.0005 & (-0.05) & TEXTEXTEXT & 0.0054 & (0.35) \\ 
            5 & TEXTEXTEXT & 0.0029 & (0.34) & TEXTEXTEXT & 0.0046 & (0.39) \\ 
            6 & TEXTEXTEXT & 0.0034 & (0.30) & TEXTEXTEXT & 0.0103 & (1.12) \\ 
            7 & TEXTEXTEXT & 0.0063 & (0.38) & & & \\ 
            8 & TEXTEXTEXT & -0.0006 & (-0.07) & & & \\ 
            9 & TEXTEXTEXT & -0.0037 & (-0.29) & & & \\ 
            10 & TEXTEXTEXT & -0.0017 & (-0.19) & & & \\ 
            11 & TEXTEXTEXT & -0.0005 & (-0.06) & & & \\ 
            12 & TEXTEXTEXT & 0.0048 & (0.57) & & & \\ 
            13 & TEXTEXTEXT & 0.0054 & (0.52) & & & \\ 
            14 & TEXTEXTEXT & 0.0026 & (0.25) & & & \\ 
            \midrule
            & Y TEXTEXTEXT & & & & \\
            \midrule
            1 & TEXTEXTEXT & 0.0001 & (0.01) & ATEXTEXTEXT & 0.0137 & (1.59)* \\ 
            2 & TEXTEXTEXT & -0.0014 & (-0.12) & TEXTEXTEXT & 0.0105 & (1.15) \\ 
            3 & TEXTEXTEXT & 0.0107 & (1.48)* & TEXTEXTEXT & 0.0061 & (0.55) \\ 
            4 & TEXTEXTEXT & 0.0040 & (0.32) & TEXTEXTEXT & 0.0109 & (0.88) \\ 
            5 & TEXTEXTEXT & 0.0091 & (1.16) & TEXTEXTEXT & 0.0044 & (0.47) \\ 
            6 & TEXTEXTEXT & 0.0034 & (0.41) & TEXTEXTEXT & -0.0021 & (-0.13) \\ 
            7 & TEXTEXTEXT & -0.0014 & (-0.13) & TEXTEXTEXT & -0.0045 & (-0.35) \\ 
            8 & TEXTEXTEXT & 0.0019 & (0.13) & TEXTEXTEXT & 0.0143 & (1.18) \\ 
            9 & TEXTEXTEXT & 0.0001 & (0.01) & TEXTEXTEXT & -0.0160 & (-1.53)* \\ 
            10 & TEXTEXTEXT & 0.0086 & (1.15) & TEXTEXTEXT & -0.0046 & (-0.15) \\ 
            11 & TEXTEXTEXT & -0.0103 & (-0.98) & TEXTEXTEXT & 0.0004 & (0.04) \\ 
            12 & TEXTEXTEXT & -0.0008 & (-0.08) & TEXTEXTEXT & -0.0015 & (-0.10) \\ 
            13 & TEXTEXTEXT & -0.0078 & (-0.68) & TEXTEXTEXT & -0.0100 & (-0.44) \\ 
            14 & TEXTEXTEXT & -0.0023 & (-0.14) & TEXTEXTEXT & 0.0054 & (0.65) \\ 
            15 & TEXTEXTEXT & -0.0065 & (-0.51) & TEXTEXTEXT & 0.0018 & (0.14) \\ 
            16 & TEXTEXTEXT & 0.0020 & (0.29) & TEXTEXTEXT & -0.0195 & (-0.91) \\ 
            17 & TEXTEXTEXT & 0.0083 & (0.82) & & \\ 
            18 & TEXTEXTEXT & 0.0009 & (0.11) & & & \\ 
            19 & TEXTEXTEXT & -0.0101 & (-0.90) & & & \\ 
            20 & TEXTEXTEXT & 0.0043 & (0.51) & & & \\ 
            21 & TEXTEXTEXT & 0.0072 & (0.75) & & & \\ 
            22 & TEXTEXTEXT & -0.0211 & (-0.94) & & & \\ 
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}

        {\raggedright \footnotesize{One-tailed t-statistics in parantheses

                Signs indicate * p $<$ 0.1, ** p $<$ 0.05, *** p $<$ 0.01} \par}
    \end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I would like to stick with `booktabs` if possible. I updated the code with the packages currently used.

Comment: Now that I saw your updated example, if you insert `\usepackage{fullpage}`, it might work with fitting everything on one page.

Comment: I edited my answer with an MWE using the `booktabs`.

Comment: Awesome, thank you very much for you help!

Comment: Doesn't the use of the `fullpage` package contradict the [OP's statement](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/501578/reduce-column-width-of-table-while-also-aligning-values-at-decimal-point/501601#comment1266808_501578) "I also need the margins to stay the same"?

Answer (score 4):

with `siunitx` and `tabularx` (that table is fit into text area):

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[format=hang,
            font={small,it},
            labelfont={bf,it},
            labelsep=space]{caption}
\captionsetup[table]{labelsep=space,justification=raggedright,singlelinecheck=off}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\usepackage{booktabs, tabularx}

%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
    \small
\caption{Sample caption}
\label{tab:example}
%
\sisetup{parse-numbers=false,
         table-format=-2.4} % integer part had to have
                            % one digit more than normally needed
                            % otherwise decimal point is overwritten
     \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} rXSSXSS @{}}
      \toprule
      & TEXTEXTEXT & {AR} & {t-stat} &  Firms  & {AR} & {t-stat} \\
      \midrule
      & \multicolumn{6}{l}{X TEXTEXTEXT}    \\
      \midrule
      1 & TEXTEXTEXT &  0.0056 &  (0.46) & TEXTEXTEXT &  0.0046 &  (0.37) \\
      2 & TEXTEXTEXT & -0.0067 & (-0.45) & TEXTEXTEXT &  0.0062 &  (0.63) \\
      3 & TEXTEXTEXT &  0.0006 &  (0.07) & TEXTEXTEXT & -0.0036 & (-0.31) \\
      4 & TEXTEXTEXT & -0.0005 & (-0.05) & TEXTEXTEXT &  0.0054 &  (0.35) \\
      5 & TEXTEXTEXT &  0.0029 &  (0.34) & TEXTEXTEXT &  0.0046 &  (0.39) \\
      6 & TEXTEXTEXT &  0.0034 &  (0.30) & TEXTEXTEXT &  0.0103 &  (1.12) \\
      7 & TEXTEXTEXT &  0.0063 &  (0.38) & & & \\
      8 & TEXTEXTEXT & -0.0006 & (-0.07) & & & \\
      9 & TEXTEXTEXT & -0.0037 & (-0.29) & & & \\
     10 & TEXTEXTEXT & -0.0017 & (-0.19) & & & \\
     11 & TEXTEXTEXT & -0.0005 & (-0.06) & & & \\
     12 & TEXTEXTEXT &  0.0048 &  (0.57) & & & \\
     13 & TEXTEXTEXT &  0.0054 &  (0.52) & & & \\
     14 & TEXTEXTEXT &  0.0026 &  (0.25) & & & \\
      \midrule
      & \multicolumn{6}{l}{Y TEXTEXTEXT}    \\
      \midrule
      1 & TEXTEXTEXT &  0.0001 &  (0.01)  & TEXTEXTEXT &  0.0137 &  (1.59)* \\
      2 & TEXTEXTEXT & -0.0014 & (-0.12)  & TEXTEXTEXT &  0.0105 &  (1.15)  \\
      3 & TEXTEXTEXT &  0.0107 &  (1.48)* & TEXTEXTEXT &  0.0061 &  (0.55)  \\
      4 & TEXTEXTEXT &  0.0040 &  (0.32)  & TEXTEXTEXT &  0.0109 &  (0.88)  \\
      5 & TEXTEXTEXT &  0.0091 &  (1.16)  & TEXTEXTEXT &  0.0044 &  (0.47)  \\
      6 & TEXTEXTEXT &  0.0034 &  (0.41)  & TEXTEXTEXT & -0.0021 & (-0.13)  \\
      7 & TEXTEXTEXT & -0.0014 & (-0.13)  & TEXTEXTEXT & -0.0045 & (-0.35)  \\
      8 & TEXTEXTEXT &  0.0019 &  (0.13)  & TEXTEXTEXT &  0.0143 &  (1.18)  \\
      9 & TEXTEXTEXT &  0.0001 &  (0.01)  & TEXTEXTEXT & -0.0160 & (-1.53)* \\
     10 & TEXTEXTEXT &  0.0086 &  (1.15)  & TEXTEXTEXT & -0.0046 & (-0.15)  \\
     11 & TEXTEXTEXT & -0.0103 & (-0.98)  & TEXTEXTEXT &  0.0004 &  (0.04)  \\
     12 & TEXTEXTEXT & -0.0008 & (-0.08)  & TEXTEXTEXT & -0.0015 & (-0.10)  \\
     13 & TEXTEXTEXT & -0.0078 & (-0.68)  & TEXTEXTEXT & -0.0100 & (-0.44)  \\
     14 & TEXTEXTEXT & -0.0023 & (-0.14)  & TEXTEXTEXT &  0.0054 &  (0.65)  \\
     15 & TEXTEXTEXT & -0.0065 & (-0.51)  & TEXTEXTEXT &  0.0018 &  (0.14)  \\
     16 & TEXTEXTEXT &  0.0020 &  (0.29)  & TEXTEXTEXT & -0.0195 & (-0.91)  \\
     17 & TEXTEXTEXT &  0.0083 &  (0.82)  & & & \\
     18 & TEXTEXTEXT &  0.0009 &  (0.11)  & & & \\
     19 & TEXTEXTEXT & -0.0101 & (-0.90)  & & & \\
     20 & TEXTEXTEXT &  0.0043 &  (0.51)  & & & \\
     21 & TEXTEXTEXT &  0.0072 &  (0.75)  & & & \\
     22 & TEXTEXTEXT & -0.0211 & (-0.94)  & & & \\
       \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
    \raggedright\footnotesize

    One-tailed t-statistics in parantheses

    Signs indicate * p $<$ 0.1, ** p $<$ 0.05, *** p $<$ 0.01
    \end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

(red lines indicate page layout)

*Note*: your table is to tall that can be fit in text area. This you can solve but defined bigger `\textheight` (by help of the package `geometry`} or using smaller font (for example `\footnotesize`}

**Addendum**:
Inspired by `\sisetup` used in @leandris answer:

```
   \begin{table}[ht]
   \footnotesize
\caption{Sample caption}
\label{tab:example}
%
\sisetup{table-space-text-pre={(},
         table-align-text-pre=false,
         table-space-text-post={)*},
         table-align-text-post=false,
         input-open-uncertainty = ,
         input-close-uncertainty = ,
        }
     \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} r*{2}{XS[table-format=-1.4]
                                             S[table-format=-1.2]}
                                  @{}}
 % table body
     \end{table}
```

gives better control over `S` columns formatting. Using `footnotesize` font size gives:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Here are three more possibilities:

Since your table is too tall to fit into the textblock and you specified that you didn't want to chang the margins, I'd suggest the use of `longtable`. This might especially come in handy if your caption gets longer than a single line or if you decide to add more rows to your table.

[image]

In the second example, I have allowed linebreaks in column 2 and 5 and used a larger font size for the table.

[image]

In the third example, I have reduced the font size to `\footnotesize`. With this, the table can fit into a single page even with a caption that has more than one or two lines.

[image]

All tables use the `siunitx` package in order to align the nubers with respect to the decimal marker.

```
 \documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}  

\usepackage[format=hang,font={small,it},labelfont={bf,it},labelsep=space]{caption} 
\captionsetup[table]{labelsep=space,justification=raggedright,singlelinecheck=off}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\sisetup{table-align-text-pre  = false,
    table-align-text-post      = false,   
    input-open-uncertainty     = ,
    input-close-uncertainty    = ,}


\usepackage{longtable} % Used for table 1
\usepackage{xltabular} % Used for table 2



\begin{document}


{\setlength{\tabcolsep}{3.25pt} \small
  \begin{longtable}{@{}rlS[table-format=-1.4]SlS[table-format=-1.4]S@{}}
  \caption{Sample caption that might be longer than a single line Sample caption that might be longer than a single line Sample caption that might be longer than a single line Sample caption that might be longer than a single line \label{tab:example}}\\
  \toprule
      & TEXTEXTEXT & {AR} & {t-stat} & Firms & {AR} & {t-stat} \\ 
      \midrule
  \endhead
  \multicolumn{7}{l}{\footnotesize One-tailed t-statistics in parantheses}\\
  \multicolumn{7}{l}{\footnotesize Signs indicate * p $<$ 0.1, ** p $<$ 0.05, *** p $<$ 0.01}
  \endlastfoot
        & \multicolumn{2}{l}{X TEXTEXTEXT} \\
      \midrule
      1 & TEXTEXTEXT & 0.0056 & (0.46) & TEXTEXTEXT & 0.0046 & (0.37) \\ 
      2 & TEXTEXTEXT & -0.0067 & (-0.45) & TEXTEXTEXT & 0.0062 & (0.63) \\ 
      3 & TEXTEXTEXT & 0.0006 & (0.07) & TEXTEXTEXT & -0.0036 & (-0.31) \\ 
      4 & TEXTEXTEXT & -0.0005 & (-0.05) & TEXTEXTEXT & 0.0054 & (0.35) \\ 
      5 & TEXTEXTEXT & 0.0029 & (0.34) & TEXTEXTEXT & 0.0046 & (0.39) \\ 
      6 & TEXTEXTEXT & 0.0034 & (0.30) & TEXTEXTEXT & 0.0103 & (1.12) \\ 
      7 & TEXTEXTEXT & 0.0063 & (0.38) & & & \\ 
      8 & TEXTEXTEXT & -0.0006 & (-0.07) & & & \\ 
      9 & TEXTEXTEXT & -0.0037 & (-0.29) & & & \\ 
      10 & TEXTEXTEXT & -0.0017 & (-0.19) & & & \\ 
      11 & TEXTEXTEXT & -0.0005 & (-0.06) & & & \\ 
      12 & TEXTEXTEXT & 0.0048 & (0.57) & & & \\ 
      13 & TEXTEXTEXT & 0.0054 & (0.52) & & & \\ 
      14 & TEXTEXTEXT & 0.0026 & (0.25) & & & \\ 
      \midrule
      & \multicolumn{2}{l}{Y TEXTEXTEXT}\\
      \midrule
      1 & TEXTEXTEXT & 0.0001 & (0.01) & ATEXTEXTEXT & 0.0137 & (1.59)* \\ 
      2 & TEXTEXTEXT & -0.0014 & (-0.12) & TEXTEXTEXT & 0.0105 & (1.15) \\ 
      3 & TEXTEXTEXT & 0.0107 & (1.48)* & TEXTEXTEXT & 0.0061 & (0.55) \\ 
      4 & TEXTEXTEXT & 0.0040 & (0.32) & TEXTEXTEXT & 0.0109 & (0.88) \\ 
      5 & TEXTEXTEXT & 0.0091 & (1.16) & TEXTEXTEXT & 0.0044 & (0.47) \\ 
      6 & TEXTEXTEXT & 0.0034 & (0.41) & TEXTEXTEXT & -0.0021 & (-0.13) \\ 
      7 & TEXTEXTEXT & -0.0014 & (-0.13) & TEXTEXTEXT & -0.0045 & (-0.35) \\ 
      8 & TEXTEXTEXT & 0.0019 & (0.13) & TEXTEXTEXT & 0.0143 & (1.18) \\ 
      9 & TEXTEXTEXT & 0.0001 & (0.01) & TEXTEXTEXT & -0.0160 & (-1.53)* \\ 
      10 & TEXTEXTEXT & 0.0086 & (1.15) & TEXTEXTEXT & -0.0046 & (-0.15) \\ 
      11 & TEXTEXTEXT & -0.0103 & (-0.98) & TEXTEXTEXT & 0.0004 & (0.04) \\ 
      12 & TEXTEXTEXT & -0.0008 & (-0.08) & TEXTEXTEXT & -0.0015 & (-0.10) \\ 
      13 & TEXTEXTEXT & -0.0078 & (-0.68) & TEXTEXTEXT & -0.0100 & (-0.44) \\ 
      14 & TEXTEXTEXT & -0.0023 & (-0.14) & TEXTEXTEXT & 0.0054 & (0.65) \\ 
      15 & TEXTEXTEXT & -0.0065 & (-0.51) & TEXTEXTEXT & 0.0018 & (0.14) \\ 
      16 & TEXTEXTEXT & 0.0020 & (0.29) & TEXTEXTEXT & -0.0195 & (-0.91) \\ 
      17 & TEXTEXTEXT & 0.0083 & (0.82) & & \\ 
      18 & TEXTEXTEXT & 0.0009 & (0.11) & & & \\ 
      19 & TEXTEXTEXT & -0.0101 & (-0.90) & & & \\ 
      20 & TEXTEXTEXT & 0.0043 & (0.51) & & & \\ 
      21 & TEXTEXTEXT & 0.0072 & (0.75) & & & \\ 
      22 & TEXTEXTEXT & -0.0211 & (-0.94) & & & \\ 
   \bottomrule
\end{longtable}
}
\newpage



{\small
  \begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{@{}r 
                                >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X
                                S[table-format=-1.4]
                                S
                                >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}XS[table-format=-1.4]
                                S@{}}
  \caption{Sample caption \label{tab:example2}}\\
  \toprule
      & TEXTEXTEXT & {AR} & {t-stat} & Firms & {AR} & {t-stat} \\ 
      \midrule
  \endhead
  \multicolumn{7}{l}{\footnotesize One-tailed t-statistics in parantheses}\\
  \multicolumn{7}{l}{\footnotesize Signs indicate * p $<$ 0.1, ** p $<$ 0.05, *** p $<$ 0.01}
  \endlastfoot
      & \multicolumn{3}{l}{X TEXTEXTEXT} \\
      \midrule
      1 & TEXTEX TEXT & 0.0056 & (0.46) & TEXTEX TEXT & 0.0046 & (0.37) \\ 
      2 & TEXTEX TEXT & -0.0067 & (-0.45) & TEXTEX TEXT & 0.0062 & (0.63) \\ 
      3 & TEXTEX TEXT & 0.0006 & (0.07) & TEXTEX TEXT & -0.0036 & (-0.31) \\ 
      4 & TEXTEX TEXT & -0.0005 & (-0.05) & TEXTEX TEXT & 0.0054 & (0.35) \\ 
      5 & TEXTEX TEXT & 0.0029 & (0.34) & TEXTEX TEXT & 0.0046 & (0.39) \\ 
      6 & TEXTEX TEXT & 0.0034 & (0.30) & TEXTEX TEXT & 0.0103 & (1.12) \\ 
      7 & TEXTEX TEXT & 0.0063 & (0.38) & & & \\ 
      8 & TEXTEX TEXT & -0.0006 & (-0.07) & & & \\ 
      9 & TEXTEX TEXT & -0.0037 & (-0.29) & & & \\ 
      10 & TEXTEX TEXT & -0.0017 & (-0.19) & & & \\ 
      11 & TEXTEX TEXT & -0.0005 & (-0.06) & & & \\ 
      12 & TEXTEX TEXT & 0.0048 & (0.57) & & & \\ 
      13 & TEXTEX TEXT & 0.0054 & (0.52) & & & \\ 
      14 & TEXTEX TEXT & 0.0026 & (0.25) & & & \\ 
      \midrule
      & \multicolumn{3}{l}{Y TEXTEXTEXT} \\*
      \midrule
      1 & TEXTEX TEXT & 0.0001 & (0.01) & ATEXTEX TEXT & 0.0137 & (1.59)* \\ 
      2 & TEXTEX TEXT & -0.0014 & (-0.12) & TEXTEX TEXT & 0.0105 & (1.15) \\ 
      3 & TEXTEX TEXT & 0.0107 & (1.48)* & TEXTEX TEXT & 0.0061 & (0.55) \\ 
      4 & TEXTEX TEXT & 0.0040 & (0.32) & TEXTEX TEXT & 0.0109 & (0.88) \\ 
      5 & TEXTEX TEXT & 0.0091 & (1.16) & TEXTEX TEXT & 0.0044 & (0.47) \\ 
      6 & TEXTEX TEXT & 0.0034 & (0.41) & TEXTEX TEXT & -0.0021 & (-0.13) \\ 
      7 & TEXTEX TEXT & -0.0014 & (-0.13) & TEXTEX TEXT & -0.0045 & (-0.35) \\ 
      8 & TEXTEX TEXT & 0.0019 & (0.13) & TEXTEX TEXT & 0.0143 & (1.18) \\ 
      9 & TEXTEX TEXT & 0.0001 & (0.01) & TEXTEX TEXT & -0.0160 & (-1.53)* \\ 
      10 & TEXTEX TEXT & 0.0086 & (1.15) & TEXTEX TEXT & -0.0046 & (-0.15) \\ 
      11 & TEXTEX TEXT & -0.0103 & (-0.98) & TEXTEX TEXT & 0.0004 & (0.04) \\ 
      12 & TEXTEX TEXT & -0.0008 & (-0.08) & TEXTEX TEXT & -0.0015 & (-0.10) \\ 
      13 & TEXTEX TEXT & -0.0078 & (-0.68) & TEXTEX TEXT & -0.0100 & (-0.44) \\ 
      14 & TEXTEX TEXT & -0.0023 & (-0.14) & TEXTEX TEXT & 0.0054 & (0.65) \\ 
      15 & TEXTEX TEXT & -0.0065 & (-0.51) & TEXTEX TEXT & 0.0018 & (0.14) \\ 
      16 & TEXTEX TEXT & 0.0020 & (0.29) & TEXTEX TEXT & -0.0195 & (-0.91) \\ 
      17 & TEXTEX TEXT & 0.0083 & (0.82) & & \\ 
      18 & TEXTEX TEXT & 0.0009 & (0.11) & & & \\ 
      19 & TEXTEX TEXT & -0.0101 & (-0.90) & & & \\ 
      20 & TEXTEX TEXT & 0.0043 & (0.51) & & & \\ 
      21 & TEXTEX TEXT & 0.0072 & (0.75) & & & \\ 
      22 & TEXTEX TEXT & -0.0211 & (-0.94) & & & \\ 
   \bottomrule
\end{xltabular}
}

\newpage


\begin{table}[ht]
\caption{Sample caption \label{tab:example3}}
\centering
 \footnotesize
  \begin{tabular}{@{}rlS[table-format=-1.4]SlS[table-format=-1.4]S@{}}
  \toprule
      & TEXTEXTEXT & {AR} & {t-stat} & Firms & {AR} & {t-stat} \\ 
      \midrule
      & \multicolumn{2}{l}{X TEXTEXTEXT} \\
      \midrule
      1 & TEXTEXTEXT & 0.0056 & (0.46) & TEXTEXTEXT & 0.0046 & (0.37) \\ 
      2 & TEXTEXTEXT & -0.0067 & (-0.45) & TEXTEXTEXT & 0.0062 & (0.63) \\ 
      3 & TEXTEXTEXT & 0.0006 & (0.07) & TEXTEXTEXT & -0.0036 & (-0.31) \\ 
      4 & TEXTEXTEXT & -0.0005 & (-0.05) & TEXTEXTEXT & 0.0054 & (0.35) \\ 
      5 & TEXTEXTEXT & 0.0029 & (0.34) & TEXTEXTEXT & 0.0046 & (0.39) \\ 
      6 & TEXTEXTEXT & 0.0034 & (0.30) & TEXTEXTEXT & 0.0103 & (1.12) \\ 
      7 & TEXTEXTEXT & 0.0063 & (0.38) & & & \\ 
      8 & TEXTEXTEXT & -0.0006 & (-0.07) & & & \\ 
      9 & TEXTEXTEXT & -0.0037 & (-0.29) & & & \\ 
      10 & TEXTEXTEXT & -0.0017 & (-0.19) & & & \\ 
      11 & TEXTEXTEXT & -0.0005 & (-0.06) & & & \\ 
      12 & TEXTEXTEXT & 0.0048 & (0.57) & & & \\ 
      13 & TEXTEXTEXT & 0.0054 & (0.52) & & & \\ 
      14 & TEXTEXTEXT & 0.0026 & (0.25) & & & \\ 
      \midrule
      & \multicolumn{2}{l}{Y TEXTEXTEXT}\\
      \midrule
      1 & TEXTEXTEXT & 0.0001 & (0.01) & ATEXTEXTEXT & 0.0137 & (1.59)* \\ 
      2 & TEXTEXTEXT & -0.0014 & (-0.12) & TEXTEXTEXT & 0.0105 & (1.15) \\ 
      3 & TEXTEXTEXT & 0.0107 & (1.48)* & TEXTEXTEXT & 0.0061 & (0.55) \\ 
      4 & TEXTEXTEXT & 0.0040 & (0.32) & TEXTEXTEXT & 0.0109 & (0.88) \\ 
      5 & TEXTEXTEXT & 0.0091 & (1.16) & TEXTEXTEXT & 0.0044 & (0.47) \\ 
      6 & TEXTEXTEXT & 0.0034 & (0.41) & TEXTEXTEXT & -0.0021 & (-0.13) \\ 
      7 & TEXTEXTEXT & -0.0014 & (-0.13) & TEXTEXTEXT & -0.0045 & (-0.35) \\ 
      8 & TEXTEXTEXT & 0.0019 & (0.13) & TEXTEXTEXT & 0.0143 & (1.18) \\ 
      9 & TEXTEXTEXT & 0.0001 & (0.01) & TEXTEXTEXT & -0.0160 & (-1.53)* \\ 
      10 & TEXTEXTEXT & 0.0086 & (1.15) & TEXTEXTEXT & -0.0046 & (-0.15) \\ 
      11 & TEXTEXTEXT & -0.0103 & (-0.98) & TEXTEXTEXT & 0.0004 & (0.04) \\ 
      12 & TEXTEXTEXT & -0.0008 & (-0.08) & TEXTEXTEXT & -0.0015 & (-0.10) \\ 
      13 & TEXTEXTEXT & -0.0078 & (-0.68) & TEXTEXTEXT & -0.0100 & (-0.44) \\ 
      14 & TEXTEXTEXT & -0.0023 & (-0.14) & TEXTEXTEXT & 0.0054 & (0.65) \\ 
      15 & TEXTEXTEXT & -0.0065 & (-0.51) & TEXTEXTEXT & 0.0018 & (0.14) \\ 
      16 & TEXTEXTEXT & 0.0020 & (0.29) & TEXTEXTEXT & -0.0195 & (-0.91) \\ 
      17 & TEXTEXTEXT & 0.0083 & (0.82) & & \\ 
      18 & TEXTEXTEXT & 0.0009 & (0.11) & & & \\ 
      19 & TEXTEXTEXT & -0.0101 & (-0.90) & & & \\ 
      20 & TEXTEXTEXT & 0.0043 & (0.51) & & & \\ 
      21 & TEXTEXTEXT & 0.0072 & (0.75) & & & \\ 
      22 & TEXTEXTEXT & -0.0211 & (-0.94) & & & \\ 
   \bottomrule
   \multicolumn{7}{l}{\footnotesize One-tailed t-statistics in parantheses}\\
  \multicolumn{7}{l}{\footnotesize Signs indicate * p $<$ 0.1, ** p $<$ 0.05, *** p $<$ 0.01}
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 for `\sisetup`.  It works quite unexpected well. I need to make some more tests how to use it.